# Problems with commuting matrices and determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Show that if $A,B$ are two $2 \times 2$ matrices with integer elements such that $AB=BA$, then $\det(A^2+B^2) \ne 3n^4,$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$.

My try: Knowing that the two matrices commute, I wrote $A^2+B^2$ as $(A+iB)(A-iB)$, so the determinant is $\vert \det(A+iB)\vert ^2=3n^4.$

Comment: @FreeSalad I edited my question.

Comment: OK, so $\det(A+iB)$ would be a Gaussian integer $x + iy$, and $3n^4$ would be the sum of squares of two integers...

Comment: there is also no need for $A$ and $B$ to be $2\times 2$ matrices

Comment: @RobertIsrael How can I continue?

Comment: @JJR How can I continue?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ only if $x$ and $y$ are both divisible by $3$.  Then consider $(x/3)^2 + (y/3)^2$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try is good. It implies that $\det(A^2+B^2) = |\det(A+iB)|^2 = x^2+y^2, \; x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence you have written a positive integer as a sum of two squares. It remains to show that it cannot be $3n^4$. For this you need a number theory theorem:

**Theorem:** A positive integer $n$ is a sum of two squares if and only if in the prime decomposition of $n$ every prime of the form $3+4m$ occurs an even number of times.

See e.g. Theorem 6 [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400twosquares.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400twosquares.pdf)